# How to convert such dictionary data format to html best way?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I got a lot of such strings

`"x _I _aaa 1. _cool. value1, value2, value3, value4; o> lorem ipsum, delirium; o> Cogito ergo sum o> homo homini lupus est. 2. _warm. value5, valu6, valu7; o> amore ipsum lorem mortem. _II _bbb 1. _grey. one; two. three;"`

which I want to see like that:

```
x
   I _aaa 
      1. _cool. value1, value2, value3, value4; 
            а> lorem ipsum, delirium; 
            б> Cogito ergo sum; 
            в> homo homini lupus est. 
      2. _warm. value5, valu6, valu7; 
            а> amore ipsum lorem mortem. 
   II _bbb 
      1. _grey. one; two. three;
```

So I need to translate the string to html:

```
<p class="a">x</p>  
    <p class="b">I _aaa</p> 
    <ul class="c">
        <li class="d">_cool. value1, value2, value3, value4;
            <ul class="f">
                <li class="e">lorem ipsum, delirium; </li>
                <li class="e">Cogito ergo sum </li>
                <li class="e">homo homini lupus est. </li>
            </ul> </li>
        <li class="d">_warm. value5, valu6, valu7; </li>
        <li class="e">а> amore ipsum lorem mortem.  </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="b">II _bbb</p> 
    <ul class="c">
        <li class="d">_grey. one; two. three; </li>
    </ul>
```

Is there a name (like CSV, XML) for that data format?

Maybe there is a library for parsing it?

What the best way you see to do that job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the source data into a hash using a specific format, you can use a library called [Cobra vs Mongoose](http://cobravsmongoose.rubyforge.org/) to convert the hash to XML.